# kernel-image-puller pod of JEG 3.2.2 getting connection refused 111 error

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub, jupyter-irkernel

I am using jupyter enterprise gateway 3.2.2 using helm installation but while fetching kernel images getting below error.

```
kernel_image_puller.t2] Attempt 3 to pull image 'elyra/kernel-r:3.2.2' failed with exception: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionRefusedError(111, 'Connection refused'))
```

Answer (score 0):

As i am using K8s so change below settings in yaml config of Jupyter enterprise gateway.

```
 criSocket: /run/containerd/containerd.sock
```